# Can DPDK selectively init NIC ports

Tags: c, linux, networking, dpdk, mellanox

I'm using an dual-port NIC, Mellanox ConnectX-5, and the DPDK version is dpdk-stable-19.11.3. After configuration, the call of  `rte_eth_dev_count_avail()` returns `2`. But only one port of my ConnectX-5 NIC is connected to the other machine. All I can find is to init all available ports like this.

```c
RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(portid)
    if (port_init(portid, mbuf_pool) != 0)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot init port %u\n", portid);
```

Can dpdk selectively init ports? Or is there any way to make `rte_eth_dev_count_avail()` returning `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes one can selectively init ports by passing the right PCIe `Bus:Device:Function` address as a whitelist. Hence only desired ports will pop up in the application.

How to do it:

1. create a dummy application to take in all DPDK port.
2. Initialize and start the dpdk ports. Check for link-state and create port-mask (global variable) which filters in application logic.
3. Invoke `rte_eth_dev_stop & rte_eth_dev_close` for link down ports.
4. Invoke rte_eal_cleanup.
5. Use the port-mask, as an argument for `execv` to invoke your desired DPDK application.

this way you can run your application with valid ports to it.

But relying on `rte_eth_link_get` is tricky because

- if the other end is connected to dpdk-pktgen, first your DPDK application has to init the NIC locally.
- if connected to linux box, the nic has to be bought up first with `ifconfig [other nic] up`
- at times one needs to check `link.link_speed` if its valid.
- certain PMD needs write to PCIe mapped register, hence has to dev_configure and port_init to get a reliable reading for link status.

Hence safest and recommended way to use is `identify the NIC PCIe B:D:F in Linux driver and then whitelist the ports by using option -w for the desired port under igb_uio/virtio-pci`. This can be done by bind all NIC back in linux by

1. `lshw -c network -businfo` will list NIC and PCIe `Bus:Device:Function` with kerel device name and driver.
2. use `ethtool [eth device name] | grep Link` to identify the link is connected.

for reference, you can use https://github.com/vipinpv85/DPDK-APP_SAMPLES/blob/master/auto-baseaddr-selector.c as template for dummy applciation.

Comment: How to `whitelist the ports by using option -w for the desired port`?

Comment: pass pcie address of your ports as command-line arguments for `RTE_EAL_INIT` which you have identified from dummy app.

Comment: if the solution work for you, please feel free to accept or upvote.

Comment: Yeah. It works and I accepted this answer.@Vipin Varghese

Answer (score 1):

Another quick way to assign a particular port out all available ports to DPDK application by using DPDK tool [dpdk-devbind.py](http://code.dpdk.org/dpdk/v19.11/source/usertools/dpdk-devbind.py) and EAL port initialization will pick port which is assigned to UIO/VFIO kernel driver. Below are devbind script steps to identify port current status and how to bind required port to DPDK.

```
[root@linux usertools]# ./dpdk-devbind.py --status

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:00:03.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' if= drv=e1000 unused=vfio-pci
0000:00:04.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' if= drv=e1000 unused=vfio-pci

[root@linux usertools]# ./dpdk-devbind.py --bind=vfio-pci 00:04.0
[root@linux usertools]# ./dpdk-devbind.py --status

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:00:04.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' drv=vfio-pci unused=e1000

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:00:03.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' if= drv=e1000 unused=vfio-pci
```

[EDIT-1] based on the updated question from author, the request is identify from the available DPDK ports which is connected? as mentioned above answer one needs to use `rte_eth_link_get`

Comment: the question can dpdk selectively init ports which are already included in available list of ports.

Comment: This maybe a way to make `rte_eth_dev_count_avail()` returning `1`.@Vipin Varghese If I unbind one my `ConnectX-5` NIC port with `mlx5_core`, it will be unavailable for `dpdk`. Did do mean this?@Sunil Bojanapally

Comment: @Wen, yes when you unbind device will probe to respective kernel driver rather dpdk pmd driver making it only one port available through out.